# Copying/trimming an array to a certain size

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**EDIT**: *making it clear that I need it for multidimensional arrays (at any depth level)*

I need to cut down the size of an array to get only a portion of it, but this needs to be done recursively. For example, take the following case:

```
$a = array(
  'a',
  'b' => array(
    'x' => array(
      'aleph',
      'bet'
      ),
    'y'), 
  'c', 
  'd', 
  'e'
);
```

what I need is that after copying only 4 elements I'll get the following resulted array:

```
$a = array(
  'a',
  'b' => array('x' => array(
      'aleph'
    ),
  ), 
);
```

and not...

```
$a = array(
  'a',
  'b' => array('x' => array(
      'aleph',
      'bet'
      ),
    'y'), 
  'c', 
  'd', 
);
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example contains either 2 or 3 values, depending on wether you count an array as one, or as the number of containing elements. However, there are no 4 values anywhere :?

Comment: I guess you could say there are 4 keys involved, one for each of a, b, x, y

Comment: If you copy the array in the second code block and run count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE); on it, you'll see that you get '4' as a result...

Answer (score 1):

You can try `**Note :  dual-dimensional`

```
    $a = array("a","b" => array('x','y'),"c","d","e");
$new = __cut($a);


function __cut($array, $max = 4) {
    $total = 0;
    $new = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $total ++;
            $diff = $max - $total;
            $slice = array_slice($value, 0, $diff);
            $total += count($slice);
            $new[$key] = $slice;
        } else {
            $total ++;
            $new[$key] = $value;
        }
        if ($total >= $max)
            break;
    }
    return $new;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  'b' => 
    array
      0 => string 'x' (length=1)
      1 => string 'y' (length=1)
```

Comment: Cool, but I'm looking for multidimensional algorithm, not dual-dimensional... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayTrim($array, $size,  $finalArray = null){
    global $count;
    foreach ($array AS $key => $val){
        if($size == $count)
            return $finalArray;
        $count++;
        if(is_array($val)){
            $finalArray[$key] = array();
            $finalArray[$key] = arrayTrim ($val, $size,  $finalArray[$key]);
        }
        else
            $finalArray[$key] = $val;
    }
    return $finalArray;
}
$a = array( "a"=> array('xa', 'ya'), "b" => array('x', 'y'),  "c", "d", "e" );

print_r(arrayTrim($a, 4));
```

should work fine